# OkHttp 3 how to create cookie domain start with '.'

Tags: java, okhttp

I am using okhttp 3 create cookie

```
var c1 = new Cookie.Builder()
    .path("/")
    .domain(".test.org")
    .name("cookie-name")
    .value("cookie-value")
    .httpOnly().secure().build();
```

An exception occurred

"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:unexpected domain: .test.org" in
`.domain(".test.org")`

what should I do to create the domain in the cookie is the first character is '.'

Comment: `The Domain attribute specifies which hosts can receive a cookie. If unspecified, the attribute defaults to the same host that set the cookie, excluding subdomains.` - see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies Host can't starts from '.'

Answer (score 1):

You can omit the leading `.` without a change in behavior. From [RFC 6265](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6265#section-5.2.3):

> If the first character of the attribute-value string is %x2E ("."):
>
> ```
>   Let cookie-domain be the attribute-value without the leading %x2E
> ```